# Here Maps Example on Turn-By-Turn Navigation not working [Android Premium SDK]

Tags: java, android, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I am looking to build a turn-by-turn Navigation app for in-vehicle hands-free use. Currently using Android Premium SDK

I am trying to implement the following example provided on here-maps webpage: https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/turn-by-turn-navigation

Upon running the app without any changes [except for API key and authentication], only the simulation option is working well but navigation option is not responding at all.

Answer (score 0):

With limited understanding of your app, I can only assume it's due to lack of GPS signal. Navigation of HERE SDK relies on hardware GPS, make sure it's turned on and working properly, if there is no GPS position acquired, navigation might not start as expected.

Comment: Hello HERE team,
As of now I am just trying to implement the example app for turn-by-turn navigation, which is provided in this link: 
https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/turn-by-turn-navigation

I have made no changes to the code given, except for those changes needed for authentication.
Also here is the link to screen recording of the HERE guidance App I made:  https://youtu.be/1RvXYwrF9WY

As you can see. The map is initialized & the route is drawn but upon clicking either simulation or navigation option nothing else is happening. GPS is working fine too

Comment: Maybe consider to migrate to the HERE SDK Navigate Edition and try this example: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/android/Navigation